# need oracle sql returns 1 row when 0 rows are selected

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle11g

I got a headache on writing an oracle sql. When my sql returns 0 row, I need it returns "empty" instead of returning 0 rows. For example,

```
select name from employee where id=1;
```

Result:

```
0 rows selected
```

I need it returns like this:

```
Empty
```

1 row selected

Since there is no such record in db, is there a way to do that? I do need it return a value. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select name 
from employee 
where id=1
union all
select 'Empty'
from dual
where not exists (select 1 from employee where id=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

```
 SELECT NVL((select name from employee where id=1), 'Empty') name from dual
```

Thanks @Samual's idea!!

Comment: That won't work. No results is different from name being null. Following your idea the answer would be : select nvl((select name from employee where id=1), 'Empty') name from dual . That supposing that name can't be null and id is unique.

Comment: What happens if you want more than one row?

Comment: Sorry @turbot, I meant columns. You need an additional sub-select per column to be returned.